# `tcolorbox` background color change

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
   There are too many sentences and hence the following box starts from the lower part of the page.
   \begin{center}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable][colback=white, sharp corners]
            This text is quite large.
        \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

When I don't use `breakable`, the background becomes white but `The text is quite large` shifts to next page. Also the corners are sharp. But using `breakable`, the background becomes default color grey but `The text is quite large` is breaking into two pages. Also the corners become rounded.

I want to bring page breaking together with white background color and sharp corner using `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include all options into the single square brackets, e.g., you used as `\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable][colback=white, sharp corners]` but it should be as `\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=blue!5, sharp corners]`, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
   There are too many sentences and hence the following box starts from the lower part of the page.
   \begin{center}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=blue!5, sharp corners]
            This text is quite large.

\lipsum[1-5]
        \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Apart from that, I'm not sure for what purpose you need `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, hope this is not necessary...